# Passing a parameter into Angular location.search

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a url that looks like the following:

```
www.mydomain.co.uk/ui/#/index?status=111?cart=5555
```

I understand if i do:

```
var status = $location.search().status;
var cart = $location.search().cart;
```

I can get the values of status and cart, but i want to make the value after `.search()` a parameter that i pass in, e.g:

```
function getParameters(param) {

    return $location.search() + param;

}


$scope.status = getParamter(status);
$scope.cart = getParamter(cart);
```

However when i try to compile my JavaScript, the process fails at my function return statement.

Comment: why not just use `$routeParams.status` and `$routeParams.cart`? `$location.search()` isn't optimal, IMHO.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams#!/

Comment: @Claies - im using ui-router, is there a ui-router equivalent?

Comment: `ui-router` has `$stateParams`

Comment: @Claies - is $stateParams accessible within the controller? I need access within a controller, not the routeconfig, hope that makes sense

Comment: yes, `$stateParams` is exclusively meant for use in a controller.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service

Comment: @Claies - how can this work in a directive? i have tried injecting $stateParams into my directive then var teststate = $stateParams.cart; however the result is undefined

Comment: Directives don't interact with the state directly, you would need to capture the value in the parent controller and pass the value into the directive as a parameter (assuming isolate scope)

Answer (score 0):

**Router**

```
.state('myState', {
    'url': 'app/:cart/',
    ...
})
```

**HTML**

```
<a ui-sref="myState({ cart: 555})" ..>
```

or with variable

```
<a ui-sref="myState({ cart: cartNumber})" ..>

$scope.cartNumber = 555
```

**Controller**

```
function myController($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.cart = $stateParams.cart; //555
    ...
```

Comment: The value in the url is dynamic and changed at any point in time, like a currency. On page load, i want to get the current value, not set it to 555

Comment: Ok, am I missing something? You have a value in your JS that you want to put into the URL so then you can get it from the URL into JS? Seems like you struggle to pass the value somewhere and went onto a wrong street trying to use the URL to store values that dynamically update.